# In CakePHP, is it possible to block a controller's actions by default?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to have all controllers' routes/actions blocked by default after baking. So if I run the bake command for `users` I should not be able to access `http://localhost:8765/users/index/` without explicitly allowing it (preferably in routes.php).

I know I can add this manually after baking:

```
 `$routes->resources( 'Users', [ 'only' => [ ] ] );`
```

But I would prefer it to be blocked by default, and in the future I can expose it as I need.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to [extend bake? It's a large topic, but it allows fine control over the generated code.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html).

In your case, you might just want to use find/replace, unless this is something that you would be doing very often.